# Android how to use getRow sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hey i'm a noob and i know this sounds simple but i have no idea how to do it. How do you use a pre-implemented method getWord?

```
  // Getting single word
public DatabaseDictionary getWord(int id) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

  Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DICTIONARY, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
          COLUMN_ENGLISH, COLUMN_OTHER, COLUMN_TERM }, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
          new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
      cursor.moveToFirst();

  DatabaseDictionary word =   newDatabaseDictionary(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
          cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
  // return word
  return word;
}
```

I know i have to write

```
final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
db.getWord(1);
```

But how do i assign this a variable i can use? I've tried this...

```
String word = db.getWord(1);
```

And that doesn't work. Please help. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an object of `DatabaseDictionary` in your `getWord` method.

If you want a string, which string do you want? In this line:

DatabaseDictionary word =   newDatabaseDictionary(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
          cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));

you are accessing the Cursor data. Maybe you want something like this:

```
String word = cursor.getString(1);
cursor.close();
return word;
```

You don't specify which part of the data you want, so maybe you need another variable in your method call, but something like that should work for you.